# EF: Should entities have business logic?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity

I was wondering, should the entities have the capability to save changes to the context? Or have business logic that relates to that particular entity? For example:

```
ActionResult ResetPassword(UserViewModel viewModel)
{
   var user = userCollection.GetUser(viewModel.Username);
   user.ResetPassword();
}
```

where:

```
class User : Entity
{
      public string Password{ get; set; }

      public ResetPassword()
      {
           Password = ""
           context.SaveChanges();
      }
}
```

I find this a bit weird since the entity would have a reference to the context. I am not sure whether this would work either - or whether this is recommended. But I want to work on a domain where I do not have to worry about saving changes, at a higher level etc. How can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

**Update**

I have updated my example - hope its a bit clearer now :)

Answer (score 2):

According to [Domain-Driven Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) domain objects should have behavior.

You should definately read [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215):

[image]

Comment: in order to achieve domain-driven behaviour, each entity would have to have a reference to the context, as stated in the question. This seems to be fighting against the mvc .net framework. Have you attempted to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would keep my Entities as **POCO's**(Plain Old Class Objects, classes with only properties) and have a **Repositary** do methods like Insert / Update.

I can keep my Entities in a separate class library and use it in different places ( even in a different project), with a different Repository implementation.

In [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) Tutorial It is  nicely explained, how to do a **Repositary & Unit Of Work Patterns** on an MVC project which uses Entity Framework

Comment: That is interesting. See, I had a different idea. I thought the domain objects should have behaviour as @Steven mentioned. And I thought the models were effectively the entities - such as User. Perhaps a better example would be - whether a user can reset a password. I would have thought it would be the User's responsibility rather than a Repository's responsibility. What do you think Shyju / Steve?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider the `UnitOfWork` pattern between your controller and your entities.

http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html